# How to construct xpath for <span class="lbl ui_lbl_radio custom-control-description">Business</span>

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Unable to click and the error is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='prpse1']"}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="lbl ui_lbl_radio custom-control-description">Business</span>
```

Comment: Why do you want to find element with text `'prpse1'` while text is obviously `"Business"`?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Business** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath*:

  ```
  //span[@class='lbl ui_lbl_radio custom-control-description' and text()='Business']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you can use CSS selector approach as below:

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.lbl ui_lbl_radio custom-control-description")).click();